# Can such a matrix exist?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices, boolean-matrix

During my work i came up with the following problem:

I am trying to find an $n \times n$ $(0,1)$-matrix $M$, for any $n > 3$, with the following properties:

- The determinant of $M$ is even.
- For any non-empty subsets $I,J\subseteq\{1,2,3\}$ with $|I| = |J|$, the submatrix $M^I_J$ has odd determinant if and only if $I=J$.

Here $M^I_J$ denotes the submatrix of $M$ created by removing the rows with indices in $I$ and the columns with indices in $J$.

So far, I tried to find such a matrix via random sampling but I am only able to find a matrix that has all properties **except the first one**, i.e., the matrix always has an odd determinant. I tried various dimensions and different input/output sets without any success. So this makes me think:

Is that there is a dependency among the requirements, which prevents them from being simultaneously true?

or

Is it possible that such a matrix exists and can someone give me an example?

Thanks,
Etsch

Comment: do you mean random subsets or any subsets ?

Comment: It seems that $\det(M^{i_1}_{o_1}) \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$ and $\det(M^{i_1}_{o_2}) \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$ conflict with each other, because there's nothing to stop $o_1$ in one random subset being $o_2$ in another random subset. Or do you just want this to be true for a single pair of subsets $\{o_1,o_2,o_3\}$, $\{i_1,i_2,i_3\}$?

Comment: Yes, the two subsets $\mathcal{I} = \{i_1,i_2,i_3\}$ and $\mathcal{O} = \{o_1,o_2,o_3\}$ are fixed. E.g. for $n=7$ one can set $i_1 = 1$, $i_2 = 2$, $i_3 = 5$ and $o_1 = 2$, $o_2 = 3$, $o_3 = 4$ and then the question is: Is there a (7x7) matrix $M$ such that $\det(M) \equiv 0\pmod{2}$, $\det(M^{1,2,5}_{2,3,4}) \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$, $\det(M^{1,2}_{2,3})  \equiv 1\pmod{2}$ and so on, according to the defined 20 properties.

Comment: Couldn't you just fix $i_1 = 1$, $i_2 = 2$, $i_3 = 3$, $o_1 = 1$, $o_2 = 2$, $o_3 = 3$ to simplify the question and to make it easier to read?

Comment: Sure, $i_1 = 1, i_2 = 2, i_3 = 3, o_1 = 1, o_2 = 2, o_3 = 3$ is a valid choice.

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: PS. I added the graph-theory tag, as we are looking for a bipartite graph with certain properties (the number of perfect matchings is odd/even in certain subgraphs).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No such matrix exists.

The [Desnanot-Jacobi identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodgson_condensation#The_Desnanot-Jacobi_identity_and_proof_of_correctness_of_the_condensation_algorithm) says that for $i \neq j$, 
$$
\det M_{ij}^{ij} \det M = \det M_i^i \det M_j^j -\det M_i^j \det M_j^i
$$
so using this, we get
$$
\det M_{12}^{12} \det M = \det M_{1}^{1} \det M_{2}^{2} - \det M_{1}^{2} \det M_{2}^{1}
$$
But your requirements force the left-hand-side to be 0 (mod 2) and the right-hand-side to be 1 (mod 2), showing they are incompatible.

Comment: Nice!  However, now I am confused because the asker said that the second bullet in the question alone can be satisfied, which indeed contradicts the identity which you quoted.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: how does the second bullet contradict the identity? The identity matrix $I$ satisfies the second bullet, and it's easy to check that $I$ satisfies the Desnanot-Jacobi identity. (Unless you're taking $i = j$, which violates a condition in the identity that I just added to my answer.)

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was bogus, and it seems that I am more confused than I thought.  Why does the requirement in the question force the left-hand side of the second equation in your answer to be 0 mod 2?

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: I totally goofed up the notation. Let me rewrite my answer.

Comment: Now I see what you meant.  You did not have to remove the first row and the first column.

Comment: Hi Peter,

thanks for response, but according to the requirements $\det(M)^{1,2,3}_{1,2,3}$ 
as well as $\det(M)^1_1$ must be odd, which makes the left-hand-side odd.
The same holds for $\det(M)^{1,2}_{1,2}$ and $\det(M)^{1,3}_{1,3}$, both must be odd.
Only $\det(M)^{1,3}_{1,2}\det(M)^{1,2}_{1,3}$ are even, which makes the right-hand-side also even.

Comment: @Etsch: I was thinking $M$ when I wrote $M^{1,2,3}_{1,2,3}$.  I think it's correct now.

Comment: Perfect, now it makes sense, $\det(M)$ indeed must be odd. Thanks very much for your help.